# xlwings using api.autofill how to pass a range as argument for the range.autofill method

Tags: python, xlwings

I can easily fill a column with formulas on Excel using VBA and the range.autofill method:

```
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

This will take the formula/content on cell A2 (or a range) and expand it to A10.

Looking at the MSDN help I see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx

and: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838605.aspx

On xlwings I can do:

```
import xlwings as xw
rp = xw.Book(myFile)
rp.sheets('mySheet').range('A2').api.autofill(range, 0)
```

But I do not know how to pass `range`. I cannot simply type "A2:A10", I need to pass a range object.

I tried to do: `rp.sheets('mySheet').range('A2').api.autofill(rp.sheets('mySheet').range('A2:A10'), 0)` but this simply blew Python!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the underlying Range objects via `api` both times. Assuming you are on Windows, this will work:

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import AutoFillType

wb = xw.Book('Book1')
sheet = wb.sheets(1)
sheet.range('A2').api.AutoFill(sheet.range("A2:A10").api,
                               AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work on Mac:

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import AutoFillType

wb = xw.Book('euromillions.csv')
ws = wb.sheets('euromillions')

ws.range("A2").api.autofill(destination = ws.range("A2:A5").api, type = AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks, Felix Zumstein, for the provided answers. Let me add what worked on my windows system:

sheet.range("A1").api.AutoFill(sheet.range("A1:A10").api, 0)

AutoFillType.xlFillDefault was not recognized in my case, replacing this value by 0 did the job.

Comment: Are you saying thanks for one answer here and ciriticising another? Or are you trying to make your own answer according to [answer]? If not the latter please delete. If the latter please [edit] to improve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 'xlFillDefault' is an Excel enumerated value, its not xlwings. The use of 'api' indicates use of Excel VBA commands. You can import xlwings constants to obtain its value (located in the AutoFillType class), or set the constant yourself, or yes just enter 0 since that is it' value.