# Autofill the Formula to the last occupied cell in a range xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I want to drag the formula to the last occupied range of cell like excel.
I have added formula using copy paste from range CN6:CY6 to CN8:CY8 with cell referencing but now i want to drag/autofill the formula to the rest of the occupied range, how can i do it?

```
import xlwings as xw
wb=xw.Book("example.xlsb")
wb.sheets[1].range("cn8:cy8").color=None
wb.sheets[1].range("cn8:cy8").font.color = (0, 0, 0)
lastRow = wb.sheets[1].range(8,2).end('down').row
wb.sheets[1].range('CN8:CY8').api.AutoFill(lastRow,
                               AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)
```

Please Note i have "From" Range but not fixed "To" range as data may vary from time to time, i have used lastrow funtion to determine last occupied cell. how can i use lastrow in the "Autofill" line of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xlwings using api.autofill how to pass a range as argument for the range.autofill method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977016/xlwings-using-api-autofill-how-to-pass-a-range-as-argument-for-the-range-autofil)

Comment: I tried this before posting my question but it did not work for me

Comment: You should make a note that you read the suggested Post and it didn't work for you and what if anything it did/didn't do, errors etc. The method in the Post does work, though I can only state that for the windows option as answered by Felix Zumstein. If you are using MACOS then due to changes in that OS it may no longer work as listed but should still be possible.

Comment: For Windows, the line `ws.range('CN8:CY8').api.AutoFill(ws.range("CN8:CY20").api, AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)` or  `wb.sheets[1].range('N8:Y8').api.AutoFill(wb.sheets[1].range("N8:Y20").api, AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)` would copy the formulas from range 'CN8:CY8' down to 'CN20:CY20' so fill rows 9 - 20. If you've tried this then please show your code.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. it works once to define the "to" range but i dont have to range. I have updated my question little bit

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just use the last_row variable in your code.
Make sure that column B does have a last row otherwise the returned value will be the max rows of the sheet, 1048576.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import AutoFillType


xlfile = 'example.xlsb'

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(xlfile)
    wb.sheets[1].range("cn8:cy8").color = None
    wb.sheets[1].range("cn8:cy8").font.color = (0, 0, 0)
    lastRow = wb.sheets[1].range(8, 2).end('down').row

    wb.sheets[1].range('CN8:CY8').api.AutoFill(wb.sheets[1]
                      .range(f"CN8:CY{lastRow}").api, AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)


    wb.save(xlfile)
```